# WinRt media element binding C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have DataTemplate and in it I need to play a binding MediaElemnt or mp3 sounds but i cant access it from code behind when I tap on an image inside this datatemplate

```
   <Page.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="lol">
   <Image  Height="52" Width="54"  Margin="282,-1,22,49" Source="ms-appx:///png/sound-icon.png" Tapped="Image_Tapped_1"  />      
    </DataTemplate>
  </Page.Resources>
```

I tried many ways but all of them didn't play the mp3 mainly like this :

```
        private void Image_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        var music = new MediaElement()
        {
            AudioCategory = AudioCategory.ForegroundOnlyMedia,
            Source = new Uri(this.BaseUri, "ms-appx:/mp3/1.mp3")
        };
        music.Play();
```

Is there any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried "ms-appx:///mp3/1.mp3" instead of "ms-appx:/mp3/1.mp3"?

Comment: yes but not working !

Comment: Have you set build action to content for 1.mp3 from properties of 1.mp3?

Comment: yes its build action already content .

Comment: Try `music.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///mp3/1.mp3")` in `music`'s `Loaded` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer

MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.Source = new Uri("ms-apps:///mp3/1.mp3");
mp.IsInteractive = true;
```

### Change the property of 1.mp3 as follow:

1. Build Action : Content
2. Copy to Output Directory: Copy always